# Compare two pictures byte by byte in unix c

Tags: c, image, file, unix, compare

I wrote this method that compares two files, specifically pictures, and prints in output where is the difference and what it is. At this moment the result of this is that every single byte is different to the other but the image I'm comparing is the same. Can you help me out? Here is the code:

```
void compareFiles(char* path1, char* path2){
    FILE* img1;
    FILE* img2;

    if((img1 = fopen(path1,"r")) == NULL || (img2 = fopen(path2,"r")) == NULL){
        printf("ERROR fopen()\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int i=0;
    char buffer1,buffer2;

    int c;
    while ((c=fgetc(img1)) != EOF){
        fread(&buffer1, 1,1, img1);
        fread(&buffer2, 1,1, img2);
        if(buffer1 != buffer2){
            printf("Byte differs\n IMG1: %s, IMG2: %s; Position %d\n",&buffer1,&buffer2,i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    fclose(img1);
    fclose(img2);
}
```

Comment: `c=fgetc(img1)` is reading one byte from first file, but no one is doing the same for the second one. Dunno how is it *specifically pictures*, though...

Comment: The `printf` is wrong as well ... your buffers are in fact just single characters, passing an address to these for `%s` is **undefined behavior** (`%s` expects a `0`-terminated string)

Comment: And finally, *the same image* doesn't imply *the same representation in the file*. There are many possible file formats allowing for different options how to store the image.

Comment: You must also open the files in binary mode,`"rb"`

Comment: @EngeneSh, Re "*Dunno how is it specifically pictures, though...*", The *files* are specifically pictures. The OP surely mentioned this in case it matters. For example, it elicited Paul Oglivie's comment (that `"rb"` is needed).

Comment: Mmmm, if you compare a 128x128 solid red square image written as a JPEG, it will be totally different from a 128x128 solid red square written as a PNG or a TIF or a GIF, so your approach will not work well as an image comparator. Worse than that, if you compare 2 solid red rectangles both saved in PNG files against each other, they will probably still differ because the time of creation is also saved in the file... of course, as an academic exercise, it's fine to compare images byte-for-byte, but the reality is otherwise.

Comment: `if((img1 = fopen(path1,"r")) == NULL || (img2 = fopen(path2,"r")) == NULL)`???  Why did you stuff all that into one line?  If one of the calls does fail, you can't tell which one.

Answer (score 5):

```
while ((c=fgetc(img1)) != EOF)
```

This reads the first byte from `img1`.  Assuming it's not `EOF`...

```
fread(&buffer1, 1,1, img1);
```

This reads the second byte from `img1`.

```
fread(&buffer2, 1,1, img2);
```

This reads the first byte from `img2`.

```
if(buffer1 != buffer2)
```

So now we're comparing the first byte of `img2` to the second byte of `img1`.

If they happen to be equal, we'll go around the loop again, and we'll end up comparing the second byte of `img2` to the fourth byte of `img1`.

It looks like you might have thought that `fgetc` tested to see if there was another byte available, and that `fread` then read it.  But no.  `fgetc` reads one character from the file and then returns it.  If you write

```
c = fgetc(fp);
```

it's almost exactly the same as if you wrote

```
fread(&c, 1, 1, fp);
```

So a minimal fix to your program would be to get rid of the

```
fread(&buffer1, 1,1, img1);
```

line, and change the equality test to

```
if(c != buffer2)
```

But that ends up being kind of confusing -- a later reader is likely to wonder, "why is one file being read using `fgetc`, and the other using `fread`?"

If I were writing this, I might read one byte from `img1` using `getc`, and one byte from `img2` using `getc`, and compare them.  Or, I might use `fread` to read N bytes from `img1` into a character array, and N bytes from `img2` into a second character adday, and compare them using the `memcmp` function.

Also, as Paul Ogilvie mentioned in a comment, since these are binary files, when you call `fopen` to open them you should specify `"rb"` mode.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see, your solution wouldn't be good for me because I need to see which byte are different and why but all your advice made me realize what to do, thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should convert them into two bitmaps and make a header and matrix comparison. You are having trouble now because headers and tags can be different. You can find many tutorials about this topic, such as [this one on Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16821/Comparing-Two-Bitmaps-for-Equality).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other comments, the fgetc was reading a char off the stream, so the 2 streams are out of sync before the calls to fread. The following uses 2 calls to fgetc and then uses the return values for the comparison.

```
void compareFiles(char* path1, char* path2){
    FILE* img1; 
    FILE* img2; 

    if((img1 = fopen(path1,"rb")) == NULL || (img2 = fopen(path2,"rb")) == NULL){ 
        printf("ERROR fopen()\n"); 
        exit(-1); 
    }   

    int i=0;
    int byte1,byte2;

    while (((byte1=fgetc(img1)) != EOF) && ((byte2=fgetc(img2)) != EOF)){
        if(byte1 != byte2){
            printf("Byte differs\n IMG1: %c, IMG2: %c; Position %d\n",byte1,byte2,i);  
            i++; 
        } 
    }  

    fclose(img1);
    fclose(img2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so much! Your solution is much more direct and polish than what i came up with :) Thank you